# Creat Excel Macro to change a value to positive or negative based on another cell

Tags: macros

[Change in cash example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woSQA.png) 
I need column, chg to cash, to look at the ,type column, and change, column amount, to its correct number +/- In a new column.

I export the data from Quickbooks and have to be careful what I change so it is not overwritten when I update the spreadsheet from excel.

Comment: Does it have to be a macro? Any reason an IF statement won't work?

Comment: I believe an if statement could work.  I just need the correct number to pull into my pivot table that is linked to the main spreadsheet.

Comment: In your example all the values can be flipped correctly by multiplying by -1, regardless of type. Are there other scenarios where this wouldn't work?